# mysql join with two row into one

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, join

I have 2 tables table name is users and projects.the structure of table is:

user  table

```
id | name   | role  
1  | samjad | user  
2  | saneer | constructor
```

projects table

```
id | name   | user_id | constructor_id |  
1  | school | 1       | 2              |
```

**How can i get all details from both table  in a single row based on project table id.**

i want to select

```
projectname username, constroctorname, user_id, constroctor_id
```

in a single row

Comment: Thank you juan for editing my question

Comment: Thank you all its solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the user table twice - Once as users and then as constructors.

```
select p.name as projectname,
    u.name as username,
    c.name as contructorname,
    p.user_id,
    p.contructor_id
from projects p
left join user u on p.user_id = u.id
left join user c on p.contructor_id = c.id
where u.role = 'user'           -- check if the said user has role "user"
    and c.role = 'constructor'; -- check if the said constructor has role "constructor"
```

Comment: You dont need check the role, the id already tell you what role he has. Unless they have duplicated id

Comment: @Juan - Quite right. Could've done a validation that the said constructor is actually a constructor or not

Comment: then you can leave it on the query as a comment section ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do the fact you have two relation between project table and user  (one for user and one for constroctor) You can use user joined  for two time

```
  select p.name, u1.username, u2.username, p.user_id, p.constroctor_id
  from projects as p
  inner join user as u1 on p.user_id = u1.id
  inner join user as u2 on p.constroctor_id = u2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat() function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, field2, field3);
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

or CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)

Comment: You are welcome. If this solution is usefull for your, please vote and accept my solution. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a table called Constructor with columns name and constructor_id your query would be

```
select
  p.name as projectname,
  u.name as username,
  c.name as constructorname,
  u.id as userid,
  c.id as constructorid
from 
projects p 
inner join user u on p.user_id=u.id
inner join constructor c on p.constructor_id=c.id
```

Comment: actually looks like the user table have users and constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join. You probably want an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT * -- actually include only the fields you need
FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id = p.user_id
INNER JOIN Users uc ON uc.id = p.constructor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to join the tables on their keys.  In this case something like the below:

```
select p.name as projectname
     , u.name as username
     , if(u.role='constructor',u.name,null) as constructorname
     , p.user_id, p.constructor_id
  from users u
  join projects p
    on p.user_id = u.id;
```